# Cannot access HTTP headers from Cloud Endpoints Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm implementing custom authentication in Google Cloud Endpoints for an Android app. To do so, I'm sending an auth token in an HTTP header. From Android:

```
private static final String HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN = "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION";

private GoogleClientRequestInitializer requestInitializer =
    new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {

   @Override
   public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> request) throws IOException {
      HttpHeaders headers = request.getRequestHeaders();
      if (authPrefs.authToken().exists()) {
          headers.set(HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN, authPrefs.authToken().get().toString());
      }
      request.setRequestHeaders(headers);
   }
};

Api.Builder apiBuilder = new Api.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
    new GsonFactory(),
    null);

return apiBuilder.setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
         .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(requestInitializer)
         .build()
```

Then in Python I'm trying to retrieve the auth token header:

```
import os
auth_token = os.getenv('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```

auth_token is None.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out "HTTP_" was being prepended to any HTTP header sent. HTTP_AUTHORIZATION was being sent as "HTTP_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION".